# How to trigger on change event with v-calendar in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

How can I listen on `onChange` for the `v-Calendar` when change months/years is changed?

`V-model` only givers me the selected date if I change the date.

```
<v-date-picker
    mode="single"
    v-model="date"
    color="red"
    is-inline
/>

<div> {{ date }} </div>
```

Comment: did you try obviously `@change`

Comment: Yes, since change only listen when the date is clicked. not the arrows for changing the months/year, ofc this should be easy but I cant find any good examples on this.

Comment: I believe there isn't an official way to do this, looking at the docs and source code. However, you might be able to use `@update:page` to listen for this event, which is used internally. This is assuming that all the listeners are properly passed up along the component chain through Calendar and DatePicker.

https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/blob/2333e1cc91652a9e60a9697c98a6a3c7ad322c0d/src/components/CalendarPane.vue#L173

Comment: Ok, kinda strange, guess i should make some custom buttons instead.

Comment: @input works, but the `watch:` method is more versatile. Use the watch method if you also update v-model externally separate from v-calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to trigger some action when the value of the v-Calendar component was changing, and @change was not triggering anything.

I resorted using **watch** in my component script:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            date: {}
        }
    },

    watch: {
        date: function() {
            // do what you want here

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to track month change, I used `update: fromPage`
It worked for me

```
 <DatePicker
    v-model="date"
    mode="date"
    :available-dates="dates"
    is-expanded
    title-position="right"
    @update:fromPage="change"
  />
```

```js
const onChange = (e) => {
  const params = {
    month: e.month,
  };

  getAvailableDates(params);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

### `update:picker-date`

is what worked for me https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#events-update:picker-date

```js
<v-date-picker
    mode="single"
    v-model="date"
    @update:picker-date="onMonth"
    color="red"
    is-inline
/>
```

```js
const onMonth = (month) => {
    console.log('change month', month);
}
```